# Flutter ChoiceChip selected Text color

Tags: flutter, widget

How to set a specific color to the text of the selected chip with a ChoiceChip widget ?
"selectedColor" is only setting the background color of the selected chip.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `labelStyle` property to set text-color of `ChoiceChip`.

```
ChoiceChip(
  label: Text('Hi'),
  selected: isSelected,
  labelStyle: TextStyle(
    color: isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone comes across this in the future and wants to use themes to set the selected label text color:

```
ThemeData example = ThemeData(
  chipTheme: ChipThemeData(
      showCheckmark: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      selectedColor: Colors.blue,
      labelStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: ChipLabelColor()
      )
  ),
);

class ChipLabelColor extends Color
    implements MaterialStateColor {
  const ChipLabelColor() : super(_default);

  static const int _default = 0xFF000000;

  @override
  Color resolve(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
      return Colors.white; // Selected text color
    }
    return Colors.black; // normal text color
  }
}
```

This example creates a chip that has black text (and a transparent background) that changes to white when the chip is selected (with a blue background)

The [MaterialStateColor class is documented here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateColor-class.html) with an example that resembles the above code. While the entire label cant use material state property I found that the label color was accepting of the material state class to resolve with the different states.

Comment: can we do the same to the labelStyle itself? something like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77409250/flutter-chipthemedatas-labelstyle-not-working-with-materialstatetextstyle

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [lilpomm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10337400/lilpomm)'s answer, if you want to use a `Theme` you can simply just use a `secondaryLabelStyle`.
From its documentation:

> Overrides the default for [ChoiceChip.labelStyle], the style of the [DefaultTextStyle] that contains the chip's label.
> This only has an effect on label widgets that respect the [DefaultTextStyle], such as [Text].

So this way you can edit the selected text color, as well as the other style attributes:

```dart
ThemeData example = ThemeData(
  chipTheme: ChipThemeData(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      selectedColor: Colors.black,
      secondaryLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
  ),
);
```