# Flutter ChipThemeData's labelStyle not working with MaterialStateTextStyle

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have this themeData that I provide to my `MaterialApp`

```dart
  ThemeData get themeData => ThemeData(
        ...
        chipTheme: _chipTheme(),
      );
```

where `_chipTheme` is just a custom `ChipThemeData`
, it has this `labelStyle` property:

```dart
        labelStyle: MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith(
          (states) {
            TextStyle? textStyle;
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              textStyle = ...
            }
            else {
              ....
            }
            return textStyle ?? const TextStyle();
          },
        ),
```

the problem is that the `labelStyle` is not being applied, and setting breakpoints/print statements inside the `resolveWith` method, I can see it is not being called, what I am doing wrong, how can I set the `labelStyle` based on the state of the chip (selected/disabled/etc...)

#### Edit 1

I know that I can normally pass a `TextStyle` instead of `MaterialStateTextStyle`, but this won't solve the problem, as I need to change the `TextStyle` based on the `MaterialState` of the chip

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
              useMaterial3: true,
        chipTheme: ChipThemeData(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
                      Color? color;
                      if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                        color = Colors.red;
                      } else {
                        color = Colors.green;
                      }
                      return color;
                    }),
                  ),),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ActionChip(label: Text("Test"), onPressed: (){});
  }
}
```

If you remove the onPressed from the ActionChip, it should jump in the disabled state.

As mentioned in the docs, you can handle following states:

> If TextStyle.color is a MaterialStateProperty,
> MaterialStateProperty.resolve is used for the following
> MaterialStates:
>
> MaterialState.disabled. MaterialState.selected. MaterialState.hovered.
> MaterialState.focused. MaterialState.pressed.

Comment: I see, my code compiles normally, and I need to change the textstyle based on the state of the chip, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Ah, okay. I edited my answer, can you check if this works for your case? I used a ActionChip to demonstrate the disabled state.

Comment: thank you but this still does not answer my question, I want to use choice chip and also in your edited answer you are not changing the text style but only the color